# Apache Wicket with Spring version dependencies

Tags: java, spring, wicket

Is there any known version dependencies between Apache Wicket and Spring? Couldn't find any from the Wicket or Wicket-Spring bridge documentation .

For example can Wicket 7 be run with Spring 5, Wicket 9 with Spring 4 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket 7.x uses Spring 4.1.x - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-7.x/pom.xml#L135

Wicket 8.x uses Spring 4.3.x - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-8.x/pom.xml#L137

Wicket 9.x uses Spring 5.3.x - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-9.x/pom.xml#L174

Wicket 10.x will use Spring 6.x - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/80726e2dae60e5893be0621761883f2dec20cac0/pom.xml#L185

You can manage the Spring version in your pom.xml and it may work or not depending on which Spring APIs you use in your application. Wicket's usage of Spring APIs is rather minimal and most probably you won't face problems.

Comment: Thank you for prompt and detailed answer :)

Comment: In fact there are plenty problems with Spring 6. You cant simply use Wicket 5 with Spring 6 because of javax to jakarta changes. Wicket 10 in fact is (as far as I can see) far from beeing released and now only in the first milestone. Spring Boot 2.7 free supports ends this year, but moving on to SB3 is simply not possible now.

Comment: @Allanon 10.0.0-M1 is quite stable! I know several projects which use it without (known) problems! Please try it and either raise issues or just drop an email at our mailing lists that it works fine for you and we will release it sooner!